# Multiple row concatenation for email distribution

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, concatenation

I am working with an organization that does not have AD distribution groups. SQL is 2012. One table has rows of an identifier and then a second row has the corresponding email addresses. I wanted to run a script to grab the email addresses based off the identifier and create one string separated by semi colons.

So:

```
SELECT [Email Address] FROM MYTABLE WHERE ID="ABC" 

Result:
123@email.com
345@email.com
567@email.com
```

I want result of 123@email.com;345@email.com;567@email.com

What would work best, recursive, pivot, SQL Concatenation?

I'd like something fairly straight forward and am just not sure what the best method is. Any tips or advice is greatly appreciated. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following :

```
DECLARE @email VARCHAR(8000)  
SELECT @email = COALESCE(@email + ';', '') + [Email Address] FROM MYTABLE WHERE ID='ABC' 
SELECT @email
```

Comment: @SQL_Noob : Glad to help you!Write back if something goes wrong).Also I have not noticed that you want to concatenate them with `;` delimeter so check updated.

Comment: That works, however, it doesn't have the semicolon as value separator. Where would that go in the COALESCE?